# How to loop through an open text file and stay open while emails are being sent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, win32com

I'm using win32com.client to connect to my outlook to send batches of emails out recurrently.

I have a text document with the body of my email but as I loop through it, after the first email every subsequent email is blank instead of having the text document:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
with open(email_txt_doc, 'r') as f:
    for company, contacts in contacts_dict.items():
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = contacts
        mail.Subject = 'Recurring Email'
        mail.Body = f.read() + '\n\n' + strategies_dict[company]
        mail.Attachments.Add(filepath/file.xlsx)
        mail.Send()
```

However, the text document 'f' stops reading in after the first loop and all the other emails are blank or just have the value from my `strategies_dict`.

#### Example:

Email1:

Please complete and return by July 31st the 2nd quarter RFIs for the strategy/ies listed below. We have attached for your convenience our three templates – Equity, International and Fixed Income.

Once completed, please forward the RFIs to my attention. Should you have any questions feel free to contact me.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Strategy_A1

Strategy_A2

...

Strategy_An

---

Email2:

Strategy_B1

Strategy_B2

...

Strategy_Bn

---

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe you need to put the mail.body before the for loop? It looks like the second f.read() will come up blank, since the file pointer is at the end of the file. But if the mail.body never changes, reading it in first seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunatley it does change. Each contact has a different list of strategies. I should probably make that clearer in my example above. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can twiddle the lines a bit like so. You can read in the main mail body, then tack on the company's personal strategies_dict as needed in a for loop outside the "with" statement.

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
with open(email_txt_doc, 'r') as f:
    main_mail_body_from_file = f.read() + '\n\n'

for company, contacts in contacts_dict.items()
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = contacts
    mail.Subject = 'Recurring Email'
    mail.Body = main_mail_body_from_file + strategies_dict[company]
    mail.Attachments.Add(filepath/file.xlsx)
    mail.Send()
```

I might add a check to make sure company is in strategies_dict as well as contacts_dict, even if they are both defaultdicts, because otherwise the promised attachments may not appear.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `read()` on a file it only works once. To fix this assign the read value to a variable.

```py
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    temp = f.read()
```

Temp is now equal to the read value, and can be substituted.